# How to compare a number from an array with the rest of the numbers from that array?

Tags: php

I have an array $numbers= array(10,14,22,39,128);
I echo one of them 
And I want to check if that number is the highest from that array and if it is I want to make it green and if it isn't it should be red. Can you help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [max](http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php) function, example:

```
if ($one_number == max($numbers)) {
    echo 'green';
} else {
    echo 'red';
}
```